# reactJs setState change property on object within an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a little bit stuck. I try to override a certain object from an array with another object from another array :

```
onStepsLayoutChange = (layout) => {
        console.log("The new layout is", layout); //Array
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            layout: layout,
            stepsData: prevState.stepsData.map(step => {
                layout.map(l => {
                  if(step.identifier === parseInt(l.i)){
                      console.log("Match", l, step); // "l" is not empty and actually matches only if "id" is identical
                      return {
                          ...step,
                          layout: l //I want to override "layout" with the current layout "l"
                      }
                  }
                });
                return step
            })
        }), () => console.log("LayoutChange:", this.state.layout, this.state.stepsData)); // "layout" in each step is empty
    };
```

Whats my fail in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is, you are missing the default behaviour of [#array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). For each array value map will return some value by default `undefined`. You are running map inside map, So the final value that stepData will have is:

```
[[...], [...], [....] ....]
```

Instead of using nested map, use [#array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) or [#array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)  and return the value.

Write it like this:

```
stepsData: prevState.stepsData.map(step => {
    let index;
    index = layout.findIndex(l => step.identifier === parseInt(l.i));

    if(index >= 0){
        return {
            ...step,
            layout: layout[index]
        }
    }

    return step;
})
```

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5];
let b = [2,3];

let result = a.map(i => {
   return b.map(j => {
      if(i === j)
         return 0;
   })
   return i;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you stepsData must be an array of arrays you forget one return:

```
onStepsLayoutChange = (layout) => {
        console.log("The new layout is", layout); //Array
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            layout: layout,
            stepsData: prevState.stepsData.map(step => {
                return layout.map(l => { //here <---
                  if(step.identifier === parseInt(l.i)){
                      console.log("Match", l, step); // "l" is not empty and actually matches only if "id" is identical
                      return {
                          ...step,
                          layout: l //I want to override "layout" with the current layout "l"
                      }
                  }
                });
                return step
            })
        }), () => console.log("LayoutChange:", this.state.layout, this.state.stepsData)); // "layout" in each step is empty
    };
```